# Error with bool function

Tags: c, function, boolean

I am a new C developer (I am used to programming in Java), and have tried create, what I thought was a simple `bool` function. Although I am getting an error which I don't understand how to fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
int main() {
    int currentNumber, round = 1;
    printf("Numbers generated will be between 1 and 20. \n");
    currentNumber = rand() % 20;
    bool validNumber = false;
    do {
        if(currentNumber != 0) {
            validNumber == true;
        } else {
            currentNumber = rand() % 20;
        }
    }while(validNumber == false);
    printf("You're on round" + ("%d", round));
    printf("You're current number is: " + ("%d", currentNumber));
    printf("Higher or Lower (H/L)?");
    char userInput [20];
    scanf("%s", &userInput);
    if((userInput[0] == 'h') || (userInput[0] == 'H')) {
        completeRound(round, 'H', currentNumber);
    } else if((userInput[0] == 'l') || (userInput[0] == 'L')) {
        completeRound(round, 'L', currentNumber);
    }
}

void completeRound(int round, char input, int currentNumber) {
    int initialVal = currentNumber, newVal;
    if(input == 'H') {
        newVal = rand() % 20;
        bool checkResult(initialVal, newVal, input);
    } else {
        newVal = rand() % 20;
        bool checkResult(initialVal, newVal, input);
    }
}

bool checkResult(int initialVal, int finalVal, char input);
bool checkResult(int initialVal, int finalVal, char input) {
    if(input == 'H') {
        if(initialVal <= finalVal) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(input == 'L') {
        if(initialVal >= finalVal) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    printf("An error has occurred! Aborting game...");
    return false;
}
```

The error is as follows:

> \main.c|39|error: conflicting types for 'checkResult'

At first, I thought that for some reason, in C you could only pass certain data types as arguments to a `bool` method, although I can not find a straight answer to this on Google. Other than that; I can not understand what it means by "conflicting types" (this is the first time I've debugged a C program.

The function I have used to call `checkResult` is as follows:

Comment: Do you have some other definition of checkResult somewhere? In Java you can have a checkResult(arg1, arg2) and a checkResult(arg1, arg2, arg3) function. In C this is not allowed.

Comment: Nope, just the one, with those arguments.

Comment: Show the code around your call to `checkResult`, especially the declarations of `initialVal`, `newVal` and `input`. BTW your `checkResult` function doesn't compile, there are typos.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have just added to function used to call `checkResult`.

Comment: What is `temp`, please post actual code. And what is `int initialVal = currentNumber, newVal;` supposed to be ? It doesn't compile.

Comment: The call should be just `value = checkResult(initialVal, newVal, temp)`. With `bool checkResult(...)` you actually declare a prototype with all arguments using a default type of `int`. (It is legal in C to declare functions inside other functions. It is more usual to declare them in headers or at the beginning of the file.)

Comment: In addition to @MOehm 's comment: you have put the prototype of `checkResult`right before the definition of `checkResult` which is pointless. You must put it _before_ you use it, that is in your case _before_ the `completeRound` function. The same goes for the `completeRound` function which is used in `main` without prototype.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, I have fixed that, and have it working properly now, thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what `printf("string" + ("%d", integer));` means... Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before calling the function you need to write its prototype also. By default compiler is considering it as return type of `int` but actually it is `bool`.

so write `bool checkResult(int initialVal, int finalVal, char input)` before calling `checkResult`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Although I am still getting the same error when I write the prototype?

Comment: where did you write the prototype? is it before the definition? does all your argument type are same as definition and prototype?

Comment: as per latest update from you , i would suggest you to write code in below order - prototype for `checkResult`, definition of `checkResult` and then `completeRound`

Comment: please put `bool checkResult(int initialVal, int finalVal, char input);` above `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a typo in your code. The line

```
bool checkResult(initialVal, newVal, temp);
```

implicitly creates a prototype for a `bool` function. The types of the arguments are omitted and default to `int` in C versions prior to C99. This declaration is in conflict with the actual declaration, whose third parameter is of type `char`.

You probably meant something like this:

```
bool okay = checkResult(initialVal, newVal, temp);
```

This defines a `bool` variable `okay` and initialises it with the result of the function call. (But note that this variable is local to the current scope, so in your example you'd lose the result immediately.)

It is legal in C to declare a function inside a function body, although it is not good practice. It is more usual to declare them in headers or at the beginning of the file.

As of C99, implicit function declarations are invalid. There also isn't a default argument or function return type of `int`. You might consider to enforce the C99 standard (eg with `-std=c99`in gcc) to avoid falling into the implicit-declaration trap.

Answer (score 1):

You have called functions before declaring them.So is the error. Because by default the return type of a c function is "int".
Add

```
void completeRound(int , char , int );
```

and

```
 bool checkResult(int , int , char);
```

after your typedef (better this way than declaring them in body of the calling function).

And since `checkResult()` is returning a value of type `bool` you better assign it to a variable of type `bool` like

```
bool okay = checkResult(initialVal, newVal, temp); this.
```